# Crashlytics not working after update Android Studio to 3.3

Tags: android-studio, gradle, api-key, crashlytics-android

So also gradle plugin updated to 3.3 and Gradle updated to 4.10. After that, Crashlytics stopped working with error:

```
Crashlytics found an invalid API key: null
```

Any ideas? I am forced to revert Gradle to make it working again. Crashlytics configured with Firebase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating `com.google.gms:google-services` to `4.2.0` helped me

Comment: Didn't help me.

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle file? (project & app module)

Comment: I think we need update both Crashlytics and Google Play Services. Try to do that.

Comment: even        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3' not working

Answer (score 1):

Updating

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip

that helped me on gradle-wrapper.properties